# Avcodec : generate OPUS header for a stream

Tags: c++, libavcodec, opus

I'm using OPUS with avcodec to encode sounds and stream it using my own protocol.

It works with the MP2 codec so far but when I'm switching to OPUS, I have this issue :

```
[opus @ 1b06d040] Error parsing the packet header.
```

I suppose that unlike MP2, I need to generate a header for my OPUS encoded data stream but I don't know how.

Can someone explain me how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from ff_opus_parse_packet() failing, which handles the raw opus packet header, what the specification calls the 'TOC' (for table-of-contents) byte and optional subframe lengths. It means libavcodec couldn't find the packet duration where it expected.

So probably your custom protocol is corrupting the data, returning the wrong data length, or you're otherwise not splitting the opus packet out of your framing layer correctly.

You don't need to invent your own protocol if you don't want to. There are two established designs: Opus over RTP for interactive use (like live chat where latency matters) is documented in [RFC 7587](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7587). For HTTP streaming, file storage for recording, playback and other applications like that use the Ogg container, documented [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-codec-oggopus). There are implementations of both of these in libavformat. See rtpenc.c, oggenc.c and oggparseopus.c if you're curious about the details.